# Figure with a different box around

Tags: floats, boxes

I'm trying to make a box around my figure like the ones in Benjamin Pierce "Types and Programming Languages" book and Luca Cardelli paper "Types Systems". Such boxes have horizontal rules and only small vertical lines on the corners.

I can't really get the hack, does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: It is easy with tikz, but I would say that it is overkill. Better wait to pure-latex solutions. Unless you already are using `tikz` in your document, of course.

Comment: have a look at `mdframed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{foo}[2][c]
{\begin{minipage}[#1]{#2}\centering
\hrule height2pt
\centerline{\vrule width2pt height 5pt\hfill \vrule width2pt height 5pt}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-4pt-1em}}
{\end{minipage}
\centerline{\vrule width2pt height 5pt\hfill \vrule width2pt height 5pt}
\hrule height2pt
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}


\begin{foo}[b]{.3\textwidth}

A \dotfill\ B \dotfill\ C\\
A \dotfill\ B \dotfill\ C\\
A \dotfill\ B \dotfill\ C
\end{foo}
\hfill
\begin{foo}[t]{.3\textwidth}

A \dotfill\ B \dotfill\ C\\
A \dotfill\ B \dotfill\ C\\
A \dotfill\ B \dotfill\ C
\end{foo}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possibility using the [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) and [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages to add the rules to the standard `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myrule}{%
  \rule{1pt}{8pt}%
  \kern-1pt\raisebox{-1pt}{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}%
  \kern-1pt\rule{1pt}{8pt}\par\smallskip#1#2#3}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled%
\def\@fs@pre{\rule{1pt}{8pt}\kern-1pt\raisebox{8pt}{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}\kern-1pt\rule{1pt}{8pt}}%
\def\@fs@post{}%
\def\@fs@mid{}%
\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse%
}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myrule,labelsep=colon}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{A test ruled figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `float` package was used to build the upper set of rules, and the `caption` package was used to define the lower ones.